# Select All rows in when count(*) = count(IDField)

Tags: sql-server, select

I have this table in SQL Server 2008.

```
id | TaskID | TaskHours
------------------------
0  | 25     | 1
1  | 25     | 0
2  | 24     | 1
3  | 24     | 2
4  | 24     | 2
5  | 23     | 0
```

I want to know how to select all by TaskID where the TaskHours all have a value > 0. I also want to select all rows by TaskID where the TaskHours have a 0 in them.

Basically I want to know if a task is completed by giving me all rows.
so Completed Tasks should show

```
id | TaskID | TaskHours
------------------------
2  | 24     | 1
3  | 24     | 2
4  | 24     | 2
```

and non completed tasks should show

```
id | TaskID | TaskHours
------------------------
0  | 25     | 1
1  | 25     | 0
5  | 23     | 0
```

I've tried

```
select * from tblTasks where TaskHours > 0
```

but I got this and I don't want 25 because it has a 0.

```
id | TaskID | TaskHours
------------------------
0  | 25     | 1
2  | 24     | 1
3  | 24     | 2
4  | 24     | 2
```

I've tried `count(*)` and `count(Taskhours) > 0` but I couldn't get any further.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For both queries, you may use exists logic.  For the first query, consider:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.TaskID, t1.TaskHours
FROM tblTasks t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tlbTasks t2
                  WHERE t2.TaskID = t1.TaskID AND t2.TaskHours = 0);
```

And for all tasks which have at least one record with zero task hours:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.TaskID, t1.TaskHours
FROM tblTasks t1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tlbTasks t2
              WHERE t2.TaskID = t1.TaskID AND t2.TaskHours = 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CTE(Common Table expressions) together with NOT EXISTS, EXISTS clause to derive the results.

```sql
DECLARE @tasks TABLE(id int, taskid int, taskhours int)

INSERT INTO @tasks 
values
(0  , 25     , 1),
(1  , 25     , 0),
(2  , 24     , 1),
(3  , 24     , 2),
(4  , 24     , 2),
(5  , 23     , 0);


;WITH CTE_TasksCompleted AS 
(
SELECT DISTINCT TaskId FROM @tasks
WHERE taskhours = 0
)
-- Completed Tasks
SELECT ot.* FROM @tasks as ot
WHERE Not exists (SELECT TaskId from CTE_TasksCompleted
WHERE taskId = ot.taskId)

;WITH CTE_TasksCompleted AS 
(
SELECT DISTINCT TaskId FROM @tasks
WHERE taskhours = 0
)
-- NotCompleted Tasks
SELECT ot.* FROM @tasks as ot
WHERE exists (SELECT TaskId from CTE_TasksCompleted
WHERE taskId = ot.taskId)
```

Completed Tasks

```
+----+--------+-----------+
| id | taskid | taskhours |
+----+--------+-----------+
|  2 |     24 |         1 |
|  3 |     24 |         2 |
|  4 |     24 |         2 |
+----+--------+-----------+
```

Not Completed Tasks

```
+----+--------+-----------+
| id | taskid | taskhours |
+----+--------+-----------+
|  0 |     25 |         1 |
|  1 |     25 |         0 |
|  5 |     23 |         0 |
+----+--------+-----------+
```